# PDO con firebird me arroja valores null cuando hay algún tilde o letra "ñ"

Tags: php, pdo, firebird

Mi tabla:

```
+--------+----------+
| U_COD  |  U_NAME  |
+--------+----------+
|   01   |  Daniel  |
+--------+----------+
|   02   |  Josías  |
+--------+----------+
|   03   |  René    |
+--------+----------+
```

Estoy conectándome y realizando una consulta simple a mi base de datos firebird de esta forma:

```
$host = 'firebird:dbname=my/dir/db_prueba.gdb;charset=UTF8';
$password = 'mypass';
$username = 'myuname';

try{
  $db = new PDO($host, $username, $password);
  $db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE,PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
}catch(PDOException $e){
  echo "Conección a la base de datos falló: " . $e->getMessage();
}

$busqueda=$db->prepare("SELECT * FROM T_PRUEBA ORDER BY U_NAME ASC");
$busqueda->execute();
$arrDatos=$busqueda->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
echo json_encode($arrDatos);
```

Pero cuando ejecuto el archivo, todos los valores que en mi base de datos incluyen algún tilde o letra "ñ" aparecen como null, de esta forma:

```
[
    {"U_COD":"01","U_NAME":"Daniel"}, 
    {"U_COD":"02","U_NAME":null},
    {"U_COD":"03","U_NAME":null}
]
```

Quisiera saber qué puedo estar haciendo mal, o si necesitan algún otro detalle de mi base de datos firebird.

Answer (score 0):

Prueba a definir el charset a utf8 en la conexión. Algo así:

```
define('DB_HOST', 'localhost');
define('DB_USER', 'SYSDBA');
define('DB_PASSWORD', 'YOUR_PASS');
define('DB_NAME', 'YOUR_DB');
define('DB_CHARSET', 'utf8');

try{

$str_conn="firebird:host=".DB_HOST.";dbname=".DB_NAME.";charset=".DB_CHARSET;
     
$dbh = new PDO($str_conn, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD, $options);
$dbh->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_AUTOCOMMIT,1);

}catch(PDOException $ex){
        
        $errMsg='Falló la conexión. Revise las credenciales.';
        echo $errMsg;    
}
```

Suerte!!